# How to update state in async callback using react hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-meadow-uuk52f?file=/src/App.js

When the onClick callback is making async action and the async action itself is doing multiple async actions, I'd like to update some states during those actions, but seems only the first time succeeded. How should I do it?

Also is there any point to use `useCallback` on `asyncGrandFather` and `asyncFather`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to use callback to update: `setSate(count => count + 1)`. And it's necessary to use `useCallback` especially these callbacks referring state or props, otherwise these variables won't get latest changes